# How to connect to Bonsai ElasticSearch on Heroku from a Java app

Tags: java, elasticsearch, heroku, bonsai-elasticsearch

I have a Java application that is using ElasticSearch API to connect to Bonsai on Heroku. After deploying my app to Heroku I've found that it will be impossible to connect to a traditional ElasticSearch address `127.0.0.1:9300` via TransportClient.

So I've changed TransportAddress to the one below after reading one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795778/connect-to-elasticsearch-heroku-database).

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                    .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("http://juniper-325345373.eu-west-1.bonsaisearch.net/"), 80));
```

However now I'm getting a `java.net.UnknownHostException: http://juniper-325345373.eu-west-1.bonsaisearch.net/: Name or service not known`

How should I correctly define the address in order to connect to Bonsai ElasticSearch?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I'd also like to know

Comment: @wesleyy not really. The only solution that I see here for now is to deploy an ElasticSearch Docker image on some hosting. And then call it from Elastic Java API without having to deal with the weird Bonsai host/port issues.

Answer (score 2):

I found very userful link on bonsai's web site. https://docs.bonsai.io/article/278-java

**1. Extract your account data from URI**

e.g. https://a1b2c3d4e:5f6g7h8i9@somehost-1234567.region-x-y.bonsaisearch.net

```
String username = a1b2c3d4e;
String password = 5f6g7h8i9;
```

**2. Extract host address**

```
String host = somehost-1234567.region-x-y.bonsaisearch.net;
String port = 443;
```

more information could be found here: https://docs.bonsai.io/article/94-connecting-to-bonsai

**3. Implement credentials provider**

```
  CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
  credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
```

**4. Implement** `RestHighLevelClient` **to connect to bonsai**

```
RestHighLevelClient restClient = new RestHighLevelClient(
        RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host,port,"https"))
           .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpAsyncClientBuilder -> 
    httpAsyncClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                       .setKeepAliveStrategy(new DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy())));`
```